# How to set `typeof this` as type of instance function parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

**TL;DR**: Is it possible to declare instance method parameter in a way that it automatically takes the same type as `this`?

---

I'm trying to define a `Comparable` interface. The naive definition would be this:

```js
interface Comparable<T> {
    equals(operand: T): boolean;
}

class Thingy implements Comparable<Thingy> {
    equals(operand: Thingy): boolean {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

But, obviously enough, an instance of some class will probably be compared with another instance of the same class. Therefore the type parameter in `Comparable<T>` will always repeat the class identifier.

I wonder, is there a way to define `Comparable` interface so that it automatically sets `operand` to be of the same type as `this`?

[This is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Comparable%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20equals(this%3A%20T%2C%20operand%3A%20typeof%20this)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Thingy%20implements%20Comparable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20value%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20equals(operand)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.value%20%3D%3D%3D%20operand.value%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B2%5D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20line%20%5B1%5D%20must%20ideally%20be%20left%20unchanged%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60operand.value%60%20on%20line%20%5B2%5D%20must%20be%20inferred%20as%20a%20number%20) what I've tried so far

Comment: Why not just type operand as `this`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Comparable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20equals(operand%3A%20this)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Thingy%20implements%20Comparable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20value%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20equals(operand%3A%20this%20)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.value%20%3D%3D%3D%20operand.value%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B2%5D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` can be used as a type, and I think it is what you are looking for:

```
interface Comparable {
    equals(operand: this): boolean;
}

class Thingy implements Comparable {
    constructor(
        public value: number
    ) {  }

    equals(operand: this ) { 
        return this.value === operand.value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Very slick! One point of clarification: when you use "this" as a type in a base class method, it seems to be specifically for the base class and does not get transferred to any implementing classes. For instance, if I have a protected method in a base class that uses "typeof this", and I try to call that protected method from a super class, the "typeof this" seems to still be the type of the base class.